# A probabilistic attempt to solve Riemann Hypothesis using Mertens function.

Tags: probability-theory, asymptotics, random-walk, riemann-hypothesis

I know that the following statement:
For every $\epsilon>0$
$$M(N)=O(N^{0.5+\epsilon})$$ is equivalent to Riemann Hypothesis (Where $M(N)$ is Mertens function).

As Mertens function behaves somehow randomly here is idea to treat this function as a translation in random walk. Each step is related to values of independent random variable which is equal to 
$$-1,0,+1$$ 
with probability respectively equal to 
$$\frac{3}{\pi^{2}},1-\frac{6}{\pi^{2}},\frac{3}{\pi^{2}}$$
I know that the behaviour of translation will be more generally but on the other hand i saw a statement that given values of probability"uniquely  determine  the  asymptotic  behavior  of  the Mertens function"

I quoted it from this:

https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1712/1712.04674.pdf

Does have it sense to use here probabilistic tools such as central limit theorem or law of iterated logarithm?

Thanks in advance for answers.